# AccuRev CLI list snapshots

Tags: snapshot, accurev

Is there any way to retrieve a list of all snapshots in a Depot/Stream using the AccuRev CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a script to parse out the snapshot streams.

Look at the accurev "show" command.

This command will list all the streams in your depot.

accurev show -p  streams

You will need to use the -fx option to generate xml format to parse out only the snapshot streams.